# Getting F# Core method not found with or without assembly redirect. What else can I do?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, fparsec, assembly-binding-redirect

I have a library that uses FParsec as a NuGet package. A separate C# project that references this library keeps throwing an error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'ParserResult`2<!!0,Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit> FParsec.CharParsers.run(Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<FParsec.CharStream`1<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit>,FParsec.Reply`1<!!0>>, System.String)'.'
```

The C# project targets .Net 4.6.1, whereas the library that uses FParsec target 4.5.  N.B. I still run into the same issue, even when this library target 4.6.1.

Auto-generate binding results is on. Moreover, I've tried to manually set the binding redirects, e.g.,

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.6.2.0" newVersion="4.6.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I expected the auto-generate bindings option to handle this correctly.

Comment: The MissingMethodException doesn't seem to come from F# Core but FParsec. Try checking the versions for that.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev, actually, the error is confusing. The actual method that cannot be found is `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc\`2`. This was a known bug in some version of FSharp.Core, by accident, and was resolved. However, some versions of FSharp.Core are now not compatible, apparently, which seems to be this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you ran into the issue reported by me to the F# team here: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/7718.

In summary, FParsec was compiled against an `FSharp.Core` version (version 4.4.0.0) that, when targeting a newer version of FSharp.Core in the rest of your project, or when using a `bindingRedirect` as you showed, will exhibit this error.

One resolution is to downgrade everything to an older version of `FSharp.Core` (namely the same as FParsec was compiled with). A better resolution is to download the FParsec source and compile it against a newer version of `FSharp.Core`. To do this:

- Download the sources of [FParsec from Github](https://github.com/stephan-tolksdorf/fparsec)
- Open your own solution, or an empty solution
- From directory `Build\VS11`, add "existing project" `FParsec.csproj` and `FParsecCS.csproj`
- Remove the `FSharp.Core` reference in FParsec by hand from the csproj file (the editor won't allow it). Remove it from FParsecCS.
- Add any version (I tested 4.3.4 and higher) of `FSharp.Core` from NuGet to both FParsec and FParsecCS projects
- Recompile
- Reference the new binaries (or the new projects) from your project

The exception will now be gone.